# SAS loop through 56 character string extract every two characters

Tags: string, loops, sas

Have a couple million records with a string like
"00 00 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 01"
String has a length of 56. All positions are filled with either a 0 or a 1.
My job is parse  the string of each record every two positions
(there are no spaces, that is just for clarification).

If there is a 1 in position two that means increment var1 +1
If there is ALSO a 1 in position four, (don't care about leading "0"'s
in position 1/3/5/9...55, etc.) increment var2 + 1, up to 28 variables.

The entire 56 len string must be parsed every two characters. Potentially
there could be 28 variables that have to be incremented, (but not realistic,
most likely there is only five or six) which could be found in any part of the
string, beginning to end (as long as they are  in position 2/4/6/8 up to 56, etc.)

This is what my boss gave me:
**if substr(BigString,2,1)='1' then var1+1;**

OK. Fine.
A) There are 27 more places to evaluate in the string.
B) there are a couple million records.

28 nested if then do loops doesn't sound like an answer (all I could think of).    At least not to me.
   **Thanx.**

Comment: So for your example above the var1 would return 7? WHat happens if you have a 1 in position 1 or 3? You need to expand your example to be more representative. There are quite a few easy solutions once you provide more details. COUNTC() is one quick approach as that simplifies to counting 1s so far. Otherwise an array to split them out and convert them to numeric is trivial as well. But need more details first.

Comment: There are only zero's in position's 1/3/5/7/9.

Comment: Row one example would  return                                                                                    
 Var   Total                                                                                                                     
Var3    1                                                                                                                          
Var6    1                                                                                                                            
Var13   1

Comment: Var 14  1                                                                                                                             
Var 16  1                                                                                                                         
Var 21  1

Comment: The next row would be processed, incrementing the current vars +1 IF one's are found in the same positions as the first row, PLUS any vars that previous were all zeros
 in the first row, but now have a "1".
 This goes on for a couple million records.                                                                          Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the problem well, this could be the solution:
EDITED 2. solution:

```
/* example with same row*/
data test;
a="00000100000100010000000001010001000000000100000000011110";output;
a="10000100000100010000000001010001000000000100011100011101";output;
a="01000100000100010000000001010001000000000100000001000000";output;
a="10100100000100010000000001010001000000000111111111111110";output;
a="01100100000100010000000001010001000000000101010101010101";output;
a="00000100000100010000000001010001000000000100001100101010";output;
run;

/* work by rows*/
%macro x;
%let i=1;
data test_output(drop=i);
 set test;
    i=1;
    %do %while (&i<=56);
        var&i.=0;
        var&i.=var&i.+input(substr(a,&i,1), best8.); 
        %let i=%eval(&i.+1);
    %end;
run;
%mend;
%x;

/* results:
a                                                          var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7   .   .
00000100000100010000000001010001000000000100000000011110    0   0   0   0   0   1   0    .......    
10000100000100010000000001010001000000000100011100011101    1   0   0   0   0   1   0    .......    
01000100000100010000000001010001000000000100000001000000    0   1   0   0   0   1   0    .......    
10100100000100010000000001010001000000000111111111111110    1   0   1   0   0   1   0    .......    
01100100000100010000000001010001000000000101010101010101    0   1   1   0   0   1   0    .......    
00000100000100010000000001010001000000000100001100101010    0   0   0   0   0   1   0    .......    
*/
```

Comment: I like the effort!!  The first two digits represent var1, second two digits represent var2, next to digits represent var3, etc.   In your example. the first row would be tablulated:          var3 1, var6 1, var8 1, var13 1, var14 1, var16 1, var 21 1.   NEXT row has a 1 in the first position (i'm pretending it's in the second position), so that increments var1 with 1, var3 1, etc.  In your example (very good btw, examples take a lot of work) there are 21 distinct/separate vars, as the string is 42 digits total, but only positions 2/4/6/8/10, etc have data.

Comment: OKs, Maybe I understood weel now. Please check this solution. did you think of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the author is trying to look for an do-loop method. So my suggest is macro `%do` or `array` statment in data step.

```
data _null_;
    text = '000001000001000100000000010100010000000001';

    y = length(text);
    array Var[28];
    do i = 1 to dim(Var);
        Var[i] + (substrn(text,i*2,1)='1');
        put i = Var[i]=;
    end;
run;
```

Kind of easy, isn't is?

Answer (score 0):

Array the variables that are to be potentially incremented according to string.  A `DO` loop can examine each part of the string and conditionally apply the needed increment.

The `SUM` statement `<variable>+<expression>` means the variable's value is automatically retained from row to row.

Due to the nature of `retain`ed variables, you might want only the final `var1-var28` values at the last row in the data.  The question does not have enough info regarding what is to be done with the `var<n>` variables.

Example:

Presume string is named `op_string` (op for operation).  Utilize logical evaluation result `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`

```
data want(keep=var1-var28); 
  set have end=done;
  array var var1-var28;
  do index = 1 to 28;
    var(index) + substr(op_string, 2 * index) = '1';  * Add 0 or 1 according to logic eval;
  end;
  if done;  * output one row at the end of the data set;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTC() to count the number of 1's in the string then.

```
data want;
set have;
value = countc(op_string, '1');
run;
```